# Oracle max(date) shows different results

Tags: sql, oracle, date, max, sql-order-by

I've got different results from the following PL/SQL queries:

Result: 2021-02-01

```
select
  max(b.snapshot_date)
from
  ACCOUNT_h b
where
  b.snapshot_date < (select max(a.snapshot_date) from ACCOUNT a);
```

Result: 2021-02-19 --> **the right one**

```
select
  max(trunc(b.snapshot_date))
from
  ACCOUNT_h b
where
  b.snapshot_date < (select max(a.snapshot_date) from ACCOUNT a);
```

Both *account* and *account_h* snapshot_date fields are DATE type!
To be sure, since Sql Developer shows dates without millennium and century, I've made them explicit.

Here is distinct date values from both tables:

**ACCOUNT_H**

> 2021-02-22, **2021-02-19**, 2021-02-18, 2021-02-17, 2021-02-16, 2021-02-15, 2021-02-12, 2021-02-05, **2021-02-01**, 2021-01-29, ..., 2020-02-01

**ACCOUNT**

> **2021-02-22**, 2021-02-01

As you can see, the expected result is the max(snapshot_date) of the account_h table less than max(snapshot_date) of the account table (i.e. 2021-02-22) --> **2021-02-19** (and not 2021-02-01).

Why results are different and the right one needs the trunc() function to work properly?
I supposed problems on data but the data type of both fields is DATE.

Thanks

---

I forgot: tables are not tables but views created from another database as partition of another table.
Database are installed on a multiserver platform: Oracle Exadata.
I don't think this is relevant for our purposes, it's just to give you a more complete scenario.

Comment: `date` type in Oracle even has time informations. Try to apply a `to_char` with a format that uses hours, minutes and seconds, so you will see the complete content and understand the behaviour you're getting

Comment: Thanks Aleksej but even considering the time part of the date: Feb, 19th 2021 is ALWAYS greater than Feb, 1st 2021; do you agree?

Comment: have you got indexes on those date columns? It could be a corrupt index causing the difference (e.g. your first query might be using the index and getting the wrong data, but the second query isn't using the index and is getting the right data from the table)

Comment: Dear Boneist, this could be an idea. I've already submitted a ticket to our database administrator. Anyway, why trunc() shouldn't use the index?

Comment: Is this reproducible or it once happen and now works? If reproducible check the *execution plans* of both queires and you should spot a difference...

Comment: Dear Marmite Bomber, yes I can reproduce the behavior: I get always the same result but only in this table. Tomorrow tables will be updated and maybe the indexes too and maybe it will work (as assumed by Boneist).

Comment: @cinghio your DBAs would just need to rebuild the index (which they should know). A corrupt index that isn't invalid is rare but it does happen and it can cause some odd results. As for `trunc()` causing an index not to be used... if you use a function on a column, then Oracle won't use an index for that column, unless you have an index on the function (a "function based index").

Comment: Dear Boneist, DBA told me that indexes and statistics are ok. Maybe it's a matter of partitioning. No solution, at the moment. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked both the query and it's returning same result **19-Feb-21**. Please check the data again. Simply try **select * from Account** and **select * from account_H**
I have created the data with your example and got your desired result from both the query. Check it out:

```
create table Account_H(snapshot_date date);
insert into Account_H values(date'2021-02-22');
insert into Account_H values(date'2021-02-19');
insert into Account_H values(date'2021-02-18');
insert into Account_H values(date'2021-02-17');
insert into Account_H values(date'2021-02-16');
insert into Account_H values(date'2021-02-15');
insert into Account_H values(date'2021-02-12');
insert into Account_H values(date'2021-02-05');
insert into Account_H values(date'2021-02-01');


create table Account(snapshot_date date);
insert into Account values(date'2021-02-22');
insert into Account values(date'2021-02-01');

select
  max(b.snapshot_date)
from
  ACCOUNT_h b
where
  b.snapshot_date < (select max(a.snapshot_date) from ACCOUNT a);
  
  select
  max(trunc(b.snapshot_date))
from
  ACCOUNT_h b
where
  b.snapshot_date < (select max(a.snapshot_date) from ACCOUNT a);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Dear Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur, I've already did it trying with my own tables create for this goal (as you did) and with other tables in the database with the same structure.
Results are correct except with the account and account_h tables.
That's STRANGE!

Comment: Would you please try select * from Account order by snapshot_date and select * from account_H order by snapshot_date to indentify how dates are being order.

Comment: Dear Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur, I've already did it and reported dates on my post, please read above. Regards

Comment: Now it's became stranger. If the order is ok the max() should pick the first from the ordered list.